# data only displaying after refresh in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, eventemitter, emit

I've card component, Home Page and Explore page. I have show all the cards in Explore page and user have the ability to favorite a particular card and it'll display in the Homepage.

the problem I have right now is

1. the favorited cards only appear in Homepage when I refresh the browser, It didn't show anything when I navigate using toolbar.
2. When I filtered particular favorited cards then delete it, it still appear. for example, I typed "food" in search bar and it appear 5 card, I delete 1 and cancel my search then the delete card still appearing. It only gone after refreshing the browser again.

Can anybody help me fix this bugs?.

Card Component favorite and unfavorited function

```
  toggleFavorite(): void {
    if (!this.card.isFavorite) {
      this.userService.addUserFavorite(this.card.type, this.card.guid, 0, 0).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.card.isFavorite = true;
          this.removeFromList.emit(this.card.id);
          this.refreshCardList.emit(true);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.userService.removeFavorite(this.card.guid, this.card.type).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.card.isFavorite = false;
          this.refreshCardList.emit(true);
          this.removeFromList.emit(this.card.id);
        }
      });
    }
```

Home Component, this is how I display user favorited card in Home page

```
  <div *ngIf="favorites.length > 0">
    <app-card-list [cards]="favorites"></app-card-list>
  </div>
```

Home Component ts

```
  favorites: List<Favorite>;
  loading: boolean;
  getUserFavs$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
  searchInput: string;
  user: User;
  query: string;
  inputCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.getUserFavs$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.userService.getUser();
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        this.favorites = user.userFavorites;
        this.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
        this.loading = false;
     this.cdr.detectChanges();  // treid this but still not working
      });
    this.getUserFavs$.next();
    this.filterChanged();
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ChangeDetectorRef...
constructor(private change: ChangeDetectorRef){
}

After getting response from service and assigning to card variable
Use this.change.detectChanges()